# CSS float right and then up?

Tags: css, css-float

I am trying to figure out if there's some way to accomplish a float (left or right) such that every new start from the border begins under the element above it. These are three elements:

```css
#red-block {
  background-color: red;
  width: 70vw;
  height: 15vh;
}
#blue-block {
  background-color: blue;
  width: 20vw;
  height: 45vh;
}
#green-block {
  background-color: green;
  width: 60vw;
  height: 15vh;
}
div {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div id="red-block">
  red-block
</div>
<div id="blue-block">
  blue-block
</div>
<div id="green-block">
  green-block
</div>
```

In this case, the green block begins at the right end after the vertical end of the blue block. Is there some way to get it to begin at the bottom of the red block instead?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

try flex.

HTML:

```
<div id="main-block">
  <div id="blue-block">

  </div>

  <div>

    <div id="red-block">

    </div>
    <div id="green-block">

    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

CSS:

```
#main-block{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}
#red-block {
  background-color: red;
  width: 70vw;
  height: 15vh;
}
#second-block{
  height: 30vh;
  width: 70vh;
}
#blue-block {
  background-color: blue;
  width: 20vw;
  height: 45vh;
}
#green-block {
  background-color: green;
  width: 60vw;
  height: 15vh;
}
```